# iPhone in-app purchase empty products list

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I finished coding my App 2 months ago and still unable to put it on Apple's store.
I want to add in-app purchase capability to my App.
I filled the iOS paid apps contract.
I created an in-app purchase product.
When I call from my code to get the list of products, I keep getting an empty list.
I tried posting my app with the product, but got rejected by apple on "metadata" telling me that I don't have the in-app purchase code in my app. Well, of course I don't have, because I can't get the item from the code (objective-c of course), and I thought that by submitting my app I will get approved.

Does anyone can help on this one? I really don't know how can this issue be resolved. What am I missing?

Here is the code I am using:

```
   - (void) requestProductData
   {
        if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
            NSLog(@"IN-APP:can make payments");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"IN-APP:can't make payments");
        }  

        SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                 initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:    @"com.mycomp.myapp"]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
   }
    - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
    (SKProductsResponse *)response
    {
        NSArray *myProduct = response.products;

        NSLog(@"items: %i", [myProduct count]);

        [request autorelease];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Before IOS 5.0 Store Kit does not operate in iOS Simulator. When running your application in iOS Simulator, Store Kit logs a warning if your application attempts to retrieve the payment queue. Testing the store must be done on actual devices.

And you can not test on the jailbreaked device.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You were really giving me some hope, but I am still getting zero items. I can attach screenshots from my itunesconnect if it helps.

Comment: This is no longer accurate. The iOS 5.0 simulator supports in-app purchases.

Comment: Anyone has an idea why am I getting an empty list?